# Sorting NSDictionary which contains another dictionary

Tags: iphone, ipad

I face the problem,  when i sort the dictionary, i can't get output from this. 
here i show my `NSMutableDictionary` which contains.

**ReasonMst** is my `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
Printing description of ReasonMst:
{
1 =     {
    nReasonNo = 1;
    vReasonCode = 1;
    vReasonDesc = "Office Purpose";
    vReasonType = O;
};
10 =     {
    nReasonNo = 10;
    vReasonCode = 10;
    vReasonDesc = Transit;
    vReasonType = O;
};
2 =     {
    nReasonNo = 2;
    vReasonCode = 2;
    vReasonDesc = Personal;
    vReasonType = O;
};
3 =     {
    nReasonNo = 3;
    vReasonCode = 3;
    vReasonDesc = Specific;
    vReasonType = O;
};
4 =     {
    nReasonNo = 4;
    vReasonCode = 4;
    vReasonDesc = "Meeting";
    vReasonType = I;
};
5 =     {
    nReasonNo = 5;
    vReasonCode = 5;
    vReasonDesc = "Meeting arrange";
    vReasonType = I;
};
6 =     {
    nReasonNo = 6;
    vReasonCode = 6;
    vReasonDesc = "NATIONAL CONFERENCE";
    vReasonType = I;
};
7 =     {
    nReasonNo = 7;
    vReasonCode = 7;
    vReasonDesc = Other;
    vReasonType = O;
};
8 =     {
    nReasonNo = 8;
    vReasonCode = 8;
    vReasonDesc = "Briefing Meeting";
    vReasonType = I;
};
9 =     {
    nReasonNo = 9;
    vReasonCode = 9;
    vReasonDesc = "Meeting At HO";
    vReasonType = I;
};
KeyList =     (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    ""
);
}
```

i want to sort this `NSMutableDictionary` to **vReasonDesc** wise.  Can any one tell me how can i do this easiest way ?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the values reassigned so that when arranged by key value, they are in order?

Comment: NO, i want sort this main dictionary as per vReasonDesc tag value. and key value same as nReasonNo...

Comment: There is no such thing as 'sorting' in the case of NSMutableDictionary - the docs say that the order in which its keys and values are present is unspecified. Dictionaries realize the concept of an unsorted collection - so this question doesn't quite make sense.

Comment: i accept directly sort is not possible. but i really need to sort this NSMutableDictionary any way, so please tell me solution if possible..

Comment: is it ok if the key values are changed or you need your keys to remain as 1,2,3,4...10?

Comment: no no,,,,key value same as nReasonNo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose ReasonMst is your NSMutableDictionary, do this

```
NSArray *key=[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[ReasonMst objectForKey:@"KeyList"]];
NSMutableArray *vReasonDesc=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *sortedKeys=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:nil];
NSDictionary *tempDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[key count]; i++) {
    [vReasonDesc addObject:[[ReasonMst objectForKey:[key objectAtIndex:i]]objectForKey:@"vReasonDesc"]];
}
[vReasonDesc sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];    

for (int i=0; i<[vReasonDesc count]; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<[key count]; j++) {
        tempDict=[ReasonMst objectForKey:[key objectAtIndex:j]];
        NSLog(@"%@ ... %@",[vReasonDesc objectAtIndex:i], tempDict);
        if ([[tempDict objectForKey:@"vReasonDesc"]isEqualToString:[vReasonDesc objectAtIndex:i]]) {
            [sortedKeys addObject:[tempDict objectForKey:@"vReasonNo"]];
        }
    }
}

NSLog(@"sdafa %@",sortedKeys);
```

sortedKeys contain the keys sorted according to your vReasonDesc values... now you can access your ReasonMst according to the keys in sortedKeys which inorder.

```
for (int i=0; i<[sortedKeys count]; i++) {
    NSLog (@"%@",[ReasonMst objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i]]);
}
```

Comment: hello, Mr. Neo
almost i get the output what i want, but still now i can't get keyname :which is nReasonNo,

here is my current output,
{
    nReasonNo = 8;
    vReasonCode = 8;
    vReasonDesc = "Briefing Meeting";
    vReasonType = I;
}

but i want 
{
 8 = {
    nReasonNo = 8;
    vReasonCode = 8;
    vReasonDesc = "Briefing Meeting";
    vReasonType = I;
 }
 16= {
    nReasonNo = 16;
    vReasonCode = 16;
    vReasonDesc = Camp;
    vReasonType = M;
 }
   KeyList = (
             8,
             16);
}

please tell me how can i get this.

Comment: Since its a dictionary it can be sorted itself. So you have to have the key in separated array and sort it accordingly and use that array of keys to access the dictionary in order. And to get the output like u showed is possible only when you print the whole dictionary at once but when u are accessing the individual object inside it you should print the key and the values separately.

Comment: i get output from this but when add dictionary its sorting change by key like 1,2,3,4,5  not as per sortedkeys array

NSMutableDictionary *std = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[sortedKeys count]; i++) {
    [std setValue:[ReasonMst objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i]] forKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
}

Comment: there is no guarantee that objects in your dictionary are displayed according to the order they are added

Comment: Thanks, Neo for your support...nice to meet you